# I can't get it to replace windows 8!

Tags: reboot

I have a windows 8 installed laptop, and have installed ubuntu, but when I reboot my system, I am given a choice to choose Ubuntu or windows 8, when I choose Ubuntu, the screen loads up and then repeats the question, this cycle is repeated endlessly, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like windows is still on your hard drive just in a separate partition. Grub is configured, done during the ubuntu install, to let you choose between ubuntu and windows. Grub will boot windows or linux... it is an advance bootloader. If you do not mind windows being on the hard drive then the easiest thing you could do is just edit windows out in the /etc/grub.conf file. Warning: You may create additional  boot problems if that is not done correctly. If this were my computer I would just erase the entire hard drive and install ubuntu thereafter. Windows is taking up uneeded drive space. Many ways to erase the hard drive. This is how I do it. I use the gparted live CD. The live CD is on sourceforge for download. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score -1):

It sounds very much like an issue with uefi settings. I haven't had to do this myself but try disabling uefi boot in bios. I think there is a better way do rather than disabling uefi as well. Hope this helps.